# Swift Perfect Docker Debugging the build process

Tags: swift, docker, docker-compose, perfect

I am woking on Swift Perfect server programming. My code is compiling on MacOS successfully and able to run on localhost. But, when I try with Linux build in Perfect Assistant, it is giving following error

```
unable to execute command: Killed
<unknown>:0: error: compile command failed due to signal (use -v to see invocation)
Failed: systemError(1, "sh: no job control in this shell\n<unknown>:0: error: build had 1 command failures\nswift-build: error: exit(1): /swift-3.0.2-RELEASE-ubuntu16.04/usr/bin/swift-build-tool -f /perfectbuild/.build_lin/release.yaml\n")
```

Tired of figuring out where the problem is and how to debug it. I'm new to docker as well. Please guide me regarding this.

When I try making linux executable I'm getting the following error

```
docker: Error response from daemon: oci runtime error: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused "exec: \".build_lin/debug/S-server\": stat .build_lin/debug/S-server: no such file or directory".
```

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to build a docker image with swift 5.2 using perfect assistant but it always uses the 4.2 images to build the deployment. PLEASE HELP!!!